# Block variable use __weak why sometimes there are values, sometimes for nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

[image]

The variables in the graph are sometimes normal, sometimes nil

Comment: Did you tried without `__weak`?

Comment: Tried, no __weak is normal. But I would like to know the reason for this is not because I used the return after the completion of this code block, __ weak reference to the release of the variables?

Comment: You don't need to use `weak` inside the signal block in this case, there is no retain cycle possible as you don't reference `self` or any instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

When marking the variable as `__weak`, no retain message is sent to it. That means that if the block outlives the variable, then when the block tries to read it, it will be null because it was not retained.

[Relevant clang doc](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html#objective-c-extensions)

Comment: But not every time for nil, and sometimes can be normal to the value.
And this situation appears on the iPhone 5 models, is not related to the processor 32 and 64?

Comment: It depends on when the block will be executed. If the block outlives the object, then the variable will be nil or worse it could be something else.